# error Attempt to invoke virtual method'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference

```
package com.example.andriod.societymaintenance;

public class NotceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    private Button mButtonChooseImage;
    private Button mButtonUpload;
    private TextView mTextViewShowUploads;
    private EditText mEditTextFileName;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    private Uri mImageUri;

    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;

    private StorageTask mUploadTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mButtonChooseImage = findViewById(R.id.button_choose_image);
        mButtonUpload = findViewById(R.id.button_upload);
        mTextViewShowUploads = findViewById(R.id.text_view_show_uploads);
        mEditTextFileName = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_file_name);
        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

        mButtonChooseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser();
            }
        });

        mButtonUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress()) {
                    Toast.makeText(NotceActivity.this, "Upload in progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    uploadFile();
                }
            }
        });

        mTextViewShowUploads.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            mImageUri = data.getData();

            Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).into(mImageView);
        }
    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    }

    private void uploadFile() {
        if (mImageUri != null) {
            StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

            mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                                }
                            }, 500);

                            Toast.makeText(NotceActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                    taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri().toString());
                            String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                            mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(NotceActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            mProgressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NotceActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_choose_image"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Choose"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.055"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.057" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_file_name"
        android:layout_width="206dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:hint="Enter File Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.954"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.068" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="292dp"
        android:layout_height="348dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_text_file_name"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.441"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.452" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.516"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.861" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_upload"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Upload"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.051"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.975" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_show_uploads"
        android:layout_width="218dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Show Uploads"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.73"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.964" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```